# Проблема: едет главное меню, при наведении

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка

Проблема следующая.

При наведении на выпадающее окно, едет всё меню.

Пробовал поэкспериментировать со значениями элементов - результата нет.

Спасибо за ответы! [Сайт.](http://www.animal.wg3036.wg01.ru/index.php)

```css
#sp-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 43px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  background-color: rgb(235, 90, 64);
  position: relative !important;
}

#sp-menu .sp-column .sp-megamenu-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sp-megamenu-parent {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.sp-megamenu-parent li:first-child {
  background-color: rgb(255, 123, 99);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.sp-megamenu-parent>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.sp-megamenu-parent>li>a,
.sp-megamenu-parent>li>span {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-family: Avenir Next Cyr Regular;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0px 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  /* font-variant-caps: petite-caps; */
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.sp-megamenu-parent .sp-dropdown.sp-dropdown-main.sp-menu-right {
  left: 0;
  width: 240px;
}

.sp-megamenu-parent .sp-dropdown .sp-dropdown-inner {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px;
}

.sp-megamenu-parent .sp-dropdown li.sp-menu-item>a,
.sp-megamenu-parent .sp-dropdown li.sp-menu-item span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #141414;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sp-menu" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-6 hidden-xs" style="position: static;">
  <div class="sp-column ">
    <div class="sp-megamenu-wrapper">
      <a id="offcanvas-toggler" href="#" aria-label="Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" title="Menu"></i></a>
      <ul class="sp-megamenu-parent menu-fade hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <li class="sp-menu-item current-item active"><a href="/index.php">Главная</a></li>
        <li class="sp-menu-item sp-has-child"><a href="/index.php/association">Об ассоциации</a>
          <div class="sp-dropdown sp-dropdown-main sp-menu-right" style="width: 240px;">
            <div class="sp-dropdown-inner">
              <ul class="sp-dropdown-items">
                <li class="sp-menu-item"><a href="/index.php/association/nashi-spetsialisty">Наши специалисты</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="sp-menu-item"><a href="/index.php/direction">Направления</a></li>
        <li class="sp-menu-item"><a href="/index.php/partner">Сотрудничество</a></li>
        <li class="sp-menu-item"><a href="/index.php/proects">Проекты</a></li>
        <li class="sp-menu-item"><a href="/index.php/teach">Обучение</a></li>
        <li class="sp-menu-item"><a href="/index.php/articles">Статьи</a></li>
        <li class="sp-menu-item"><a href="/index.php/contacts">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в `.sp-menu-item:hover ::after`, при наведение на родителя ему указывается свойство `display: block !important` из-за которого он встаёт на новую строку и ломает меню.
Удалите это свойство, оно явно там лишнее.

Файл `custom.css` строка `326`.